# How to create django dropdown list

Tags: python, html, css, django

I need to create a dropdown list in a datatable field using django in order to display all the countries and enable the user to choose one and get a response.
I have tried this code but it does not work.

**models.py**

```
   class Datatable(models.Model):
    COUNTRY_CHOICE = (
    ('MA', 'MA'),
    ('FR', 'FR'),
    ('US', 'US'),
)

    Title = models.CharField('Title',max_length=500),
    Price = models.DecimalField('Price',decimal_places = 3, max_digits = 10000),
    Currency = models.CharField('Currency',max_length=500),
    Stars = models.DecimalField('Stars',decimal_places = 3 , max_digits = 10000),
    Orders = models.PositiveIntegerField('Orders',max_length=500),
    Shipcost = models.CharField('Shipcost',max_length=500),
    Supplier = models.CharField('Supplier',max_length=500),
    Productlinks = models.CharField('Productlinks',max_length=700),
    Feedback = models.IntegerField('Feedback',max_length=700),
    Images = models.IntegerField('Images',max_length=700),
    Country = models.CharField(blank=True, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICE, max_length=100)
```

**datatable.html**

```
<th class="Country">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Customer Country
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#MA">MA</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#FR">FR</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#US">US</a>
                    </div>
                  </th>
```

**views.py** :

```
from multiprocessing import context
from django.shortcuts import render   
import pymongo
from .models import *
from .serializers import *
from .forms import *
from .codes.scraping import scrap


def home_view(request):
    context = {}
    context ['form'] = Scraping()
    return render(request,'home.html', context)
def datatable_view(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = Scraping(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject=form.cleaned_data['subject']
            scrap(subject)
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    db= client["db3"]
    col = db["aliex3"]
    products = col.find()
    context = {'products' : products}
    return render(request,'datatable.html', context)
```

Any help would be great. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop trough your countries:

First pass the countries to your context:

```
# your previous code...
products = col.find()
countries = Country.objects.all()

context = {}
context['products'] = products
context['countries'] = countries
return render(request,'datatable.html', context)
```

Then in your html file:

```
<th class="Country">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Customer Country
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    {% for country in countries %}
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#{{country}}">{{country}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</th>
```

Comment: Where to place my context ??

Comment: In your views.py

Comment: In my datatable view ? Because I have two views : home.view and datatable.view. Or I should create a new view

Comment: You should place this code in the views in charge for your template. Can you share with us the file in charge for your template display?

Comment: I have already add it to my question. Thank you so much !

Comment: Answer updated regarding your code

Comment: They give me an error that Country is not defined

Comment: Did you import Country in top of your file?

Comment: No. how to do it ?

Comment: add to the top of your file `from .models import Country`